# Does Dynamic SQL in MySQL Community Edition Ignore Indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a quick question guys. If I use dynamic SQL in a query or a stored procedure and I use indexes in my where clause to optimize performance of the report, does Dynamic SQL eliminate the effect of the indexing and results in table sort with how it calculates the results or is indexing being utilized properly?

Comment: I don't think so. What makes you think it would?

Comment: @Barmar some guy at work is arguing to death about it and I can't find any articles showing me either wise or that even discuss the topic. I know dynamic SQL turns the query into a string and it gets executed via function and I don't see why it would be the case.

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the documentation that suggests that queries executed with `PREPARE` are processed any differently from normal queries.

Comment: Arguing to death over something that can easily be tested in 43 seconds seems a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: Check [Re-factoring some internals of prepared statements in 5.7](http://mysqlserverteam.com/re-factoring-some-internals-of-prepared-statements-in-5-7/).

Comment: There are many factors that lead to an index being, or not being, used.  Please provide your specific query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.